# Oracle - Primary Key and Foreign Key

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, foreign-key-relationship

Will this scenario work?

**Table 1**

```
Column1 PK
Column2 FK
```

**Table 2**

```
Column1 PK
Column2 FK
```

Column2 of Table 2 reference Column1 of Table 1 and Column2 of Table 1 references Column1 of Table 2. Will this work at all? I think this will not.

Comment: Code it and see what happens.

Comment: think through the order of creation, and what this means to the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

It will, but one of the FK's must be nullable.  If you're looking to define a 1:1 relationship, why not simply use a shared primary key, though?  (PK on one table is the FK to the other table's PK)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work with deferred constraints.
E.g., one can create table `chicken` and table `egg`, both tables reference each other.
Constraints will be checked at commit time.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour for foreign keys is that the record with the parent key must exist before we can insert a child record.  We cannot skirt around this, even with an INSERT ALL statement, which we might hope could provide a loophole:

```
SQL> insert all
  2      into t2 values (c2, c1)
  3      into t1 values (c1, c2)
  4  select 42 as c1, 23 as c2 from dual
  5  /
insert all
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (APC.T2_FK) violated - parent key not found


SQL>
```

Deferred constraints offer a workaround.

```
SQL> alter table t2 drop constraint t2_fk
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t2 add constraint t2_fk foreign key (col_b)
  2      references t1 (col_1) deferrable initially deferred
  3  /

Table altered.


SQL> insert all
  2      into t2 values (c2, c1)
  3      into t1 values (c1, c2)
  4  select 42 as c1, 23 as c2 from dual
  5  /

2 rows created.

SQL>
```

In real life we should defer both foreign keys because we cannot be sure of the order in which any pair of records will be inserted.

However, the use of deferred constraints is always a workaround; usually they point to a failure in the application ( *cough* Hibernate *cough* ) but in this case the problem would be in the data model.  What does it mean to say `T1` is the parent of `T2` and simultaneously `T2` is the parent of `T1`?  It's a nonsense.

Also, such an arrangement enforces a 1:1 relationship, which is another red (or at least amber) flag on the data model.  Even if there is a genuine reason for a 1:1 relationship it would still be better to identify one clear parent and one clear child.

**tl:dr**

It can be done but it shouldn't be